# Selecting XML Elements with where clause SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have an XML Store in SQL Server with the following structure:

```
<ecHeaderData>
    <FirstVersionSource>System1</FirstVersionSource>
    <DMSEntryUserID>jsmith</DMSEntryUserID>
</ecHeaderData>
```

I want to return all rows where DMSEntryUserID is not blank.  I want to select both the FirstVersionSource and DMSEntryuserID in the query.

Something like this:

```
select deal_jacket_xml('/ecHeader/FirstVersionSource') as FirstVersionSource, 
deal_jacket_xml('/ecHeader/DMSEntryUserID') as DMSEntryUserID
from deal_jacket_xml
where deal_jacket_xml('NotBlank(/ecHeader/DMSEntryUserID'))=1
order by [deal_jacket_xml_id] desc
```

Comment: Your question makes little sense. Read [xml Data Type Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190798.aspx) first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I came up with.  The key thing is the parenthesis and the index specification of [1]:

```
select distinct deal_jacket_xml.value('(/eContractingData/ecHeaderData/FirstVersionSource)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as FirstVersionSource
from deal_jacket_xml
where deal_jacket_xml.value('(/eContractingData/ecHeaderData/FirstVersionSource)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') is not null
AND deal_jacket_xml.value('(/eContractingData/ecHeaderData/DMSEntryUserID)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') is not null
```

Comment: This might be done better (in performance)... Is your XML snippet the whole structure and you have this repeated in many rows of your table, or do you have XML with many repeated nodes and you have to pick out some of them?

Comment: The XML structure is giant. The snippet is just a tiny portion. There is a giant XML structure per row.